# Send data from Main Activity to Fragment not through intent or bundle but through interface in android?

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, interface

My question is simple how to send data from Main activity to fragment through interface but not through intent or bundle in android.
Please guide me thanks.

Here is my code from fragment to Activity data send through interface but I want against it Activity to fragment which I don't know how to do.

```
public interface OnRestaurantSelectedListener {
    public void onRestaurantSelected(String s);
}



  MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRestaurantSelectedListener{
    String mPosition;
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
     @Override
        public void onRestaurantSelected(String s) {
            mPosition =s;

        }

    }
```

In fragment:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    ...

    private OnRestaurantSelectedListener mOnRestaurantSelectedListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mOnRestaurantSelectedListener = (OnRestaurantSelectedListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

mOnRestaurantSelectedListener.onRestaurantSelected("AliResturant");


}
```

Comment: This question is liable to be put **on hold** as you didn't provide any relevant attempt or example - and as of now it looks like the answerer would have to do all the work for you. That also makes answers less accurate as well. This question is negatively scored - urgent action is needed - edit this post and reply!

Comment: I have edited it please check it now

Answer (score 0):

Create interface `FragmentCommunicator` as,

```
public interface FragmentCommunicator{
   public void passDataToFragment(String someValue);
}
```

In your main Activity we can use **interface** and pass data to fragment. Like below,

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
        //interface through which communication is made to fragment
        public FragmentCommunicator fragmentCommunicator;
        private Button fragmentButton;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.title_viewpager);
                fragmentButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fragmentButton);
                setUIListeners();
        }

        private void setUIListeners(){
                fragmentButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
              if(fragmentCommunicator != null)
                fragmentCommunicator.passDataToFragment("Hi from FragmentActivity");
            }
        });

       }
}
```

Access passed data in fragment like below,

```
public class CustomFragment extends Fragments implements FragmentCommunicator{
      public Context context;
      private Button activityButton;
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_frag, container, false);
             activityButton =(Button)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.activityButton);
             textView =(TextView)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
             setRetainInstance(true);
             return fragmentView;
    }

  //FragmentCommunicator interface implementation
  @Override
  public void passDataToFragment(String someValue){
   String activityAssignedValue = someValue;
   textView.setText(activityAssignedValue); 
  }
}
```